# Where should we provide the RestAPI details while using cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

What is the appropriate place to provide `RestAPI` details while using `cucumber`? i.e. In Feature file or Step Definition file?

Answer (score 2):

The `RestAPI` is not really part of the business problem you are solving. `Rest` is not your core functionality. It is just one, technical, way of using the real functionality you are building.

I would therefore not describe a RestAPI in the feature files using Gherkin. I would hide these implementation details in the glue code connecting the examples written in Gherkin with the system under test.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Where should be provide the stubbed data required for our testCases? In Step Definition or Feature file?
And what about RestAPI is changing, should we maintain a property file so that code will not be changed very frequent?

Comment: I would keep any data needed for technical reasons in the step definitions. Data that actually have a business meaning should go into the scenarios. I would not add more complexity by adding a property file. I would live with changes to the step definitions. They will be minor compared to changes in the code that implements the REST api.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber is a tool all about communication between groups of people throughout the business you are working with.

If you're working on a project alone, there is less of the need to describe features in business language (although, it is useful for drafting up ideas using a BDD mindset).

My advice, keep the feature files without code, CSS or any other things that could throw off a layperson. Move these to the step definition file instead, and describe what you're doing in terms that a layperson can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should store it in the `step_definitions` file. Keep all the coding tagged to the gherkin steps in the feature file to the `step_definitons` folder inside which you create a file.
Its always better to keep feature files without the code, they are mainly for better understanding of the testing process and business scenarios and best practise when you view it from BDD perspective.

In case your API values are frequently changing, you can also, mention the values in the cucumber gherkin steps, and pass it as an argument to the step_definitions file. So that any change in the values can be handled in the feature file itself, within the "double quotes" instead of going to the code every-time

On a side note, what `gem` are you using to test on the REST API? `Airborne?`